# PHP pagination using SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I still trying to create pagination with PHP but SQL SERVER (2008) not support offset and limit. Below you can see SQL query but I don't know what is wrong:

```
declare @offset int 
declare @limit int 
set @offset = 2;
set @limit = 20;

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY use_by_date desc ) AS RowNum FROM DB
WHERE RowNum >= @Offset
AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest your query inside another one:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY use_by_date desc ) AS RowNum 
   FROM DB) t
WHERE t.RowNum >= @Offset AND t.RowNum < @Offset + @Limit
```

Windowed functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` can only appear in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clauses.